# Cascade on update and delete wih django

Tags: python, django

I cannot find an option to cascade update or delete in the model api. Am wondering if there is a manual out there that can help me pass this db option when sycning the db.

any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) docs. It says:

> When an object referenced by a ForeignKey is deleted, Django by default emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey. This behavior can be overridden by specifying the on_delete argument.

So the default behavior is to cascade on delete, but you can change it by specifying something like this:

```
class Foobar(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET(User.objects.get_or_create(username="foooobarrrr")[0]))
```

Comment: thanks jergason, what about the on update? am still facing lots of problems with it. I keep getting errors from the mysql when I try to update a child record

Comment: Post your code. I am not sure what you mean by 'errors from the mysql when I try to update a child record.'

Comment: Please update your answer to mention that ``on_delete`` will become a required field in Django 2.0 ([Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0))