# Django model on_update=models.CASCADE related object reference

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have looked for `django` doc in their official site but i can't find the article about the `on_update` model function here in [Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/models/relations/) except for `on_delete`.

Here is an example code:

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Is there any version of `on_update`?

I have visited this [Cascade on update and delete wih django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295417/cascade-on-update-and-delete-wih-django) but there is not a clear answer about the `on_update`

I am using `mysql` and define the relationship in the `ERD` and sync it to the db and tried running the `python manage.py inspectdb` to generate the `django-model` but it shows only `models.DO_NOTHING`.

Is there a better way to achieve this, if any?

Comment: There is no `on_update` argument, and what would `on_update=models.CASCADE` mean anyway? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: that's bad, i would like to achieve the same way of mysql db does when updating a parent table the child table of reference id updates with it.

Comment: There is no direct way of `on_update` as pointed by @solarissmoke. But i suppose you can make use of `signals` in Django. But you'll have to write your own logic for the same. Though they are for a  slightly different purpose.

Comment: i know you have the knowledge of how `mysql` tables relationship works. for example `tbl1` with a pk of `id` and `tbl2` with fk of `id` referenced to `tbl1.id` which is the parent table with a relational constraint of `on update = cascade` when you update the `tbl1.id` the `tbl2.id` updates with it automatically. How can i do that in django model since there is no `on_update`?

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi yea, that is why it is so bad not to have such thing in django. and `signals` is another option i supposed.

Comment: Generally Django prefers you to leave `.id` alone. You can use `unique=True` on some other model to get the same effect, without mucking up your pks.

Comment: @AdamStarrh i have my `requirement` table with two ids defined one is `id ` with `auto increment` and one is an `emp_id` which is related to `employee.id` table, it is ok or should i delete the `auto increment id`?

Comment: If you delete after you've defined it, it might mess up your data or migrations. But FYI, if you don't define `id` in your model in the first place, then Django takes care of it automatically for you. You can still use `MyModel.objects.get(id=1)` for example, as Django includes it automatically. IMO, if its not too much trouble to remove the `id` field now, then it's worth doing, simply because it prevents future headaches.

Comment: @AdamStarrh oh that make sense, but where i can define the `unique=True`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normally adviseable to completely leave the primary key alone when setting up your Django models, as these are used by Django in a number of ways to maintain relationships between objects. Django will set them up and use them automatically.

Instead, create a separate field in your model to keep track of unique data:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.CharField(unique=True)
```

This way you can obtain the `emp_id` with `reporter_object.emp_id` and if you need it, you can still get the pk with `reporter_object.id`.

You can read about how it works it in the [Django 1.9 Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#unique)

Comment: While I don't dispute what you say, I also consider it bad form to have an "id" column if there is another column that is a natural primary key.

Consider the example of serial numbers. If you're creating a hardware DB, these are unique identifiers. Why would you introduce a meaningless column named "id" if "serial_no" is already a UUID, i.e. a prime candidate for the table's PK? But when you need to correct a wrongly entered S/N, you really want all the records that point to it to update as well, hence why you need the on_update=cascade.

Comment: I had the same thought when I built my first Django application. In the end, the theoretical "optimization" costed me a lot of development time as I had to repeatedly find ways to work around that decision. Nowdays, I like to think of the `id` field as a "Django field" that carries its own roles within my application pertaining to the operability of Django's ORM. It ended up being much less complicated to just add the extra field to my model.

Comment: True, but I prefer my frameworks to not be too opinionated on how I write my software. If it has a way to denote a field as the PK, then it should support actually using that field as a PK, including setting any constraints defined in standard ANSI SQL.

I understand that for practical reasons, as of now, we must make due with crutches such as id fields, or go into the DB and add those constraints ourselves.