# Why Django doesn't have an on_update=models.CASCADE option?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

My question comes from a situation where I want to emulate the ON UPDATE CASCADE in SQL (when I update an id and I have a Foreignkey, it is going to be automatically updated) in Django, but I realized that (apparently) doesn't exist a native way to do it.

I have visited [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758723/django-model-on-update-models-cascade-related-object-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1) where he is trying to do the same.

My question is: Why Django doesn't have a native option? Is that a bad practice? If so, why? Does that bring problems to my software or structure?

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice to think about updating key fields. Note that this field is used for index generation and other computationally expensive operations. This is why the key fields must contain a unique and unrepeatable value that identifies the record. It does not necessarily have to have a direct meaning with the content of the register, it can be an autonumeric value. If you need to update it, you may need to put the value in another field of the table to be able to do it without affecting the relationships.

It is for this reason that you will not find in Django the operation you are looking for.